# What is the execution order of the fields in partial classes?

Tags: c#, static, partial-classes

```
public class Report
{
    public static int A = B + 2;
    public static int B = A + 2;
}
```

AFAIK, in a class it executes the fields in the order of their presence in the class. Referring the first time to `Report` class, the fields will be initialized as `A = 2` and `B = 4`

But what is the order in partial classes?

```
public partial class Report
{
    public static int A = B + 2;
}

public partial class Report
{
    public static int B = A + 2;
}
```

Maybe if the classes are in the same file, it still executes in the order of presence in the file. Or what?

But/And what is the order if the partial classes are in different files?

By the way, I am asking this out of curiosity.

Comment: Because it is confusing. Moving a public declaration shouldn't change the code produced. It could at least product a warning

Comment: Well, according to me, the class, in this case, execute in FCFS order. The class written first is executed first in this case.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I'm trying to get this *better* specified in the ECMA version of the C# 5 spec...